# Viewing SOAP returned by a web service

Tags: soap, wsdl, vb.net-2010

I created a web service reference in my VS2010 project, and configured it with a WSDL service address URL. VS2010 created a nice proxy class for me to consume the web service.

I am getting a result that I don't like, and, in an effort to troubleshoot, I'd like to see the XML coming back from the web service. What is the simplest way to do so? I'd like to be able to do it within my Visual Studio debugging session, but if I have to go outside that, so be it.

I am trying to make the following work:

```
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        Dim reader As System.IO.StreamReader = Nothing

        Dim hwrResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(**request**.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim responseStream As System.IO.Stream = hwrResponse.GetResponseStream()

        Dim xtrSmp As New System.Xml.XmlTextReader(responseStream)
        Dim strXm As String = xtrSmp.ReadInnerXml()
        xtrSmp.Close()

        hwrResponse.Close()
```

but I don't know what my **request** should be.

Comment: Did you use "Add Service Reference"? Then you can turn on [WCF Tracing and Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx). In any case, you can use Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks. I did so. It shows me the traffic between my app and the web service but it doesn't show me what was in the response object. That's what I really need.

Comment: You did which one? And they both show both the request and the response.

Comment: I added this to my app.config

Comment: and the svclog file it built doesn't have the response content. What did I miss?

Comment: The svclog always shows all of the responses. I suspect that there _is_ no response.

Comment: OK found it thanks!!!!!!!!

Comment: And I am getting back the content I expect. Now to figure out why my proxy class doesn't properly reflect the message being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Your **REQUEST** should be a REQUEST Object whiich is configured to access the SOAP service you are trying to access...

You can find out more here...

HTTPWEBRESPONSE object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx

HTTPWEBREQUEST object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these
WebServiceStudio (http://webservicestudio.codeplex.com/),
Storm (http://storm.codeplex.com/)
or the outstanding Eclipse WSDL Editor and Web Service Explorer (look at http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Introduction_to_the_WSDL_Editor)

These will let you invoke your service methods with an ad-hoc GUI client generated from WSDL and access both request and response XML.
The list of tools above is of course incomplete.